# How to increment the value of an array by 1 in a foreach-loop of another array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, key-value

I am making a program that must count how many times a value exists in an array.
This is my code so far:

```
$aArray1 = array();
$nCount = 1;
foreach ($_SESSION['array2'] as $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($value, $aArray1)) {
        // Increment the value of the existing key(number).
    }else{
        // add $value to $aArray1 and give it a value 1.
        $aArray1[$value] = $nCount;
    }
}
```

I want to know how I can increment the value of the existing number in $aArray1 by 1.

When I put the numbers:`(4-4-5-6-7-7-7-8-4-4)` in my array by using 10 textboxes with the post method and I print my `$aArray1`, it shows this:

```
Array ( [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 1 [7] => 1 [8] => 1 )
```

But I want it to show this:

```
Array ( [4] => 4 [5] => 1 [6] => 1 [7] => 3 [8] => 1 )
```

please can anybody help me.

Comment: Try [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) instead

Comment: I dont want to use array_count_values function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be reduced to:

```
$aArray1 = array();
foreach ($_SESSION['array2'] as $value) {
    if (!isset($aArray1[$value])) {
        $aArray1[$value] = 0;
    }
    $aArray1[$value]++;
}
```

And going further - this is the same what `array_count_values` does. So, use it instead:

```
$aArray1 = array_count_values($_SESSION['array2']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['array2'] = array(4,4,5,6,7,7,7,8,4,4,4,8);
$aArray1 = array();

foreach ($_SESSION['array2'] as $value) {
 if (array_key_exists($value, $aArray1)) {
      $aArray1[$value] = ($aArray1[$value] + 1);
    // Increment the value of the existing key(number).
  }else{
    // add $value to $aArray1 and give it a value 1.
    $aArray1[$value] = 1;
  }
}
```

For Result: print_r($aArray1);

`Array ( [4] => 5 [5] => 1 [6] => 1 [7] => 3 [8] => 2 )`